# Evaluating derivative of a spline using splev in Scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I have created a bspline using splprep as below from a set of points:

```
tck,uout = splprep([x,y],s=0.,k=2,per=False)
```

Now, I am trying to evaluate the derivative of a spline using:

```
dx,dy = splev(uout,tck,der=1)
```

I find that splev returns two lists for the derivative.

Given that the Spline is parametrized (say in u), does it return dx/du and dy/du ?

If not how to evaluate the derivative (dy/dx) properly ?

Comment: If  `retval[0]` from `splev` is dx/du, and `retval[1]` is dy/du; then `retval[1]/retval[0]` is the derivative you seek, i.e. you just divide them and the `du`s "cancel out".  However, I can't confirm that that is the correct interpretation of the return values.

Comment: The latter part is what I am interested is. I am not sure what the return values represent.

Comment: If I read the documentation correctly, `splev` returns the spline function evaluated at `u`, so I'd guess `x(u)` and `y(u)`; not the derivates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if der = 1 the the lists are the values of dx/du and dy/du at each point. The gradient is then dy/dx = dy/du / dx/du.

I'm slightly concerned about the splprep call: s is optional, but if defined it should have a value of about the same as the number of points (larger means smoother). per is an integer value, not a boolean. And cubic splines are better behaved than quadratic.  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splprep.html